# Angular2 passing services to local component variable

Tags: angular

What I would like to do is have my variable `loggedIn` verify whether a user is logged in to my Angular2 Firebase app. So far nothing happens, and I do not get any errors.

`authService` is entered correctly, so there are no errors there. I haven't included my constructors in the code for that reason.

`isuser` is a local variable in my nav.component, and I want my `isuser` value to be set to the service `isLogged` value.

My **auth.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './user.interface';

declare var firebase: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

public loggedIn = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    signinUser(user: User){
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    isLogged(showLog: boolean){this.loggedIn.emit(showLog);}
    logout(){firebase.auth().signOut();}

}
```

My **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';

declare var firebase: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private authService: AuthService){}

ngOnInit(){
    var self = this;
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user){this.authService.isLogged(true);}
    else {this.authService.isLogged(false);}
}

}
```

My **nav.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

declare var firebase: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html'
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
    signInForm: FormGroup;
    private isuser: boolean;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService){
    this.signInForm = new FormGroup({
        'email': new FormControl(),
        'password': new FormControl()
    });
  }

  onSignup(){
    this.authService.signinUser(this.signInForm.value);
  }

  onLogout(){
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    var self = this;
    this.authService.loggedIn.subscribe(
    retuser => self.isuser = retuser);
  }

}
```

My **navigation.component.html**

```
<div id="signIn" *ngIf="!isuser">
    <form [formGroup]="signInForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignup()" class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" formControlName="email" />
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" formControlName="password" />
        <button class="btn btn-info">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="signedIn" *ngIf="isuser">
    <p>Welcome dude</p>
    <p>View Profile</p>
    <p (click)="onLogout()">Log Out</p>
</div>
```

For further clarification, what I am trying to mimic is this following code:

```
isAuthenticated(){
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user){return true;}
    else {return false;}
}
```

I want code that operates the same way on my **auth.service**. Instead of using a function I want to use the Event Emitter.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I have a `div *ngIf="isuser"` on my nav.component, and my DOM does not seem to acknowledge it. I have another `div *ngIf=!isuser`. of the both of them, only the latter shows.

Comment: Please add more code. You don't need `self` if you use `=>` `this` will do.

Comment: The `ngIf` is still missing

Comment: added the html. thnks in advance for taking a look.

Comment: So the problem is that the login form stays visible when isuser is set? What value does it have?

Comment: the issue is that `isuser` does not respond to my authentication. in this instance, it shows the form regardless of whether or not i am logged in.

Comment: Have you checked what `<div>{{isuser}}</div>` shows?

Comment: It does not show anything

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I can just suggest to add `console.log(...)` statements where exactly the current behavior is different from what you expect.